# Apache SSL VirtualHosts on a single IP using UCC/SAN certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, certificate

I need to host several Apache virtual hosts with SSL from a single IP.

Now - I understand that because SSL wraps around the HTTP request, there's no way to know which host is being requested until a public key has been sent to the client first. This essentially breaks the possibility of SSL virtual hosts using a standard SSL certificate.

I have obtained a Unified Communications Certificate (UCC), otherwise known as a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) certificate. This allows me to serve the same certificate for multiple domains.

I would like this to be the certificate served by Apache for *any* SSL request - and then have Apache resolve the virtual host as usual, once the encryption has been established.

How should I configure Apache for this? I have tried to research how this can be done, but all I can find are quotes which say that it is possible, but no specifics:

---

wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

> While Apache can renegotiate the SSL
>   connection later after seeing the
>   hostname in the request (and does),
>   that's too late to pick the right
>   server certificate to use to match the
>   request hostname during the initial
>   handshake, resulting in browser
>   warnings/errors about certificates
>   having the wrong hostname in them.

serverfault.com/questions/48334/apache-virtual-hosts-with-ssl

> Incidentally, it is possible to have
>   multiple SSL-secured named virtual
>   hosts on a single IP address - I do it
>   on my website - but it produces all
>   sorts of warnings in the Apache logs,
>   and certificate warnings in the
>   browser. I certainly wouldn't
>   recommend it for a production site
>   that needs to look clean.
>   -David Jul 31 at 4:58

www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm

> **Virtual Host Multiple SSL sites on a single
>   IP address.** Hosting multiple
>   SSL-enabled sites on a single server
>   typically requires a unique IP address
>   per site, but a certificate with
>   Subject Alternative Names can solve
>   this problem. Microsoft IIS 6 and
>   Apache are both able to Virtual Host
>   HTTPS sites using Unified
>   Communications SSL, also known as SAN
>   certificates.

---

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tested this on my apache 2.2.14 instance and it worked fine:

Use the NameVirtualHost directive (to ports.conf):

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

define your vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.siteA.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/apache22/htdocs/siteA"
  SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/my/cert"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/my/key"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.siteB.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/apache22/htdocs/siteB"
  SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/my/cert"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/my/key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I used this [link](http://www.crsr.net/Notes/Apache-HTTPS-virtual-host.html) as a resource.

Comment: 's answer is correct. One thing that did trip me up for a LOOOONNNNNNGGGGG time was that i had a typo where i had ```<Virtual *:433>```... the correct port is 443! Ugh, hours of my life lost on this one... Hope my pain was not in vain and this helps someone...